# Can I add azure functions to a DPS using Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions, azure-iot-dps

I'm new to both Terraform and Azure. In a timespan of 6 weeks I have to create an IoT solution. I've only got 3 weeks left.

I have to provision devices in an IoT hub using a DPS and if 'm not wrong, a DPS uses azure functions to do so.

My question is, how can I add azure functions to a dps using terraform or is this not possible and do I have it all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPS does not require an Azure Function for basic functionality.  That's only needed if you're doing [custom allocation policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/how-to-use-custom-allocation-policies?tabs=windows).  If all you want to do is have an IoT Hub assigned from a pool of one or more Hubs, then one of the built-in allocation policies will work, as described in the [overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/about-iot-dps#features-of-the-device-provisioning-service):

> Multiple allocation policies to control how DPS assigns devices to IoT
> hubs in support of your scenarios: Lowest latency, evenly weighted
> distribution (default), and static configuration via the enrollment
> list. Latency is determined using the same method as Traffic Manager.

The documentation explains [how to select this in the Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/tutorial-set-up-cloud#set-the-allocation-policy-on-the-device-provisioning-service), and since you mention you're using Terraform, the provider does this using the `allocation_policy` setting according to the [provider documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/iothub_dps).

I understand you're under a small time crunch but you might find the self-paced training at Microsoft Learn for the [AZ-220](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/certifications/exams/az-220?tab=tab-learning-paths) exam worth your time.  There is a learning path about device provisioning, and the information on load balancing is covered in that (for example, at [this lesson](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/examine-device-provisioning-service-terms-concepts/4-service-concepts?ns-enrollment-type=LearningPath&ns-enrollment-id=learn.wwl.provision-iot-devices-at-scale-by-using-device)).

Comment: I would be interested if there's a way of using Terraform to actually set `allocation_policy` to Azure Function. It is not mentioned it in the documentation you linked, it only mentions the other options: `Hashed`, `GeoLatency` or `Static`.

Comment: that feels like a separate question but in any event, reading the provider source at https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/807f0fd916fa81e0cdb3a5c411010c5e5842d59c/internal/services/iothub/iothub_dps_resource.go#L174 line 174, you can't right now.  Probably worth opening an issue if you're looking for that capability,